# Prove that for $P(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ the set $S = \left\{p : \text{prime and }p \mid P(n) \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$ is infinite

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, analytic-number-theory

Prove that for $P(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, $P(x)$ non-constant, the set $S = \left\{p : \text{prime and }p \mid P(n) \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right\}$ is infinite.

could someone please give me some advice on how to start this proof.

Comment: Does "for $n\in\mathbb Z$" mean for _some_ $n\in\mathbb Z$ or for _all_ $n\in\mathbb Z$ or what? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: for some $b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Outline:**  The result is obvious if the constant term of $P$ is $0$. So assume the constant term is non-zero.

Let $p_1,\dots,p_k$ be any primes that do not divide the constant term of $P$, and let $M_k$ be their product.  Show that for large enough $w$, $P(wM_k)$ is divisible by a prime different from the $p_i$.

Comment: What do you mean by constant term?

Comment: If $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$, then $a_0$. Or more simply $P(0)$.